# Unable to show json data on current view - Linkedin iOS Integration (Swift 4.2)

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, closures, linkedin-api

I'm having an issue getting the contents of the variable "firstName" to show up on the current view.

I have a segmented viewcontroller that has two tabs. I wanted to show firstName on the label "nameLabel" which is one the main container view using the snippet of code below.

```
linkedinHelper.authorizeSuccess({ (lsToken) -> Void in
    print("linkedin token: \(lsToken)")               

    linkedinHelper.requestURL("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,picture-urls::(original),positions,date-of-birth,phone-numbers,location)?format=json", requestType: LinkedinSwiftRequestGet, success: { (response) -> Void in                
        let profileDictionary:[String : Any] = response.jsonObject as! [String : Any]

        self.linkedinprofile.firstName = profileDictionary["firstName"] as! String

        let firstName = profileDictionary["firstName"] as! String
        self.nameLabel?.text = firstName            
    })                    
}, error: { (error) -> Void in
    //Encounter error: error.localizedDescription     
}, cancel: { () -> Void in
    //User Cancelled!            
})
```

However, after this code executes, the label stays empty. I experimented with this quite a bit to no avail. But when I replaced the label with a label from the second container view, when I click on that container view, the label shows the content I need!

Your help on this will be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks,

Comment: Try amending your question with some JSON. People will not look up the LinkedIn API just to help you. Please print out some problematic JSON first and post a reasonable amount of it in your question. This should give us enough information to help you. On StackOverflow you are basically asking people to do you a favour, so you should make it as easy as possible for them to do so.

Comment: Can you do me a favor and leave this post? Would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to update `nameLabel` in the main thread. All UI updates must happen there.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.nameLabel?.text = firstName
}
```

Or perhaps that's a moment when `nameLabel` does not exist yet. Put a breakpoint there and have a look whether it's not `nil`.

Comment: I did that and it didn't work. I found a bad but working solution which is to put a button that calls this closure whenever it's pressed. The screen is blank at first and only after I press the button does the label get the data. I think it has something to do with it being in a closure as I could see from debugging it that it doesn't get the data until later as the closure skips over and then comes back to execute the code inside it.

Comment: @swiftLearner Closure is asynchronous. It gets executed once request is resolved and that might take a while. Perhaps, update the question with your current solution for us to see and try to help.